# regexp_substr- extract numbers in multiline text

Tags: plsql, regexp-substr

I have a string in oracle table as below. I need to extract the amount after the text "Monthly Tax Amount(Property Taxes) : ". Each of the item is in new line and amount corresponding to the item is mentioned in the same line next to the description. I tried developing some regexp_substr function without much success. Kindly help resolve this.

```
"New-Escrowed Payment Quote:
Effective Date(Projected - Good Through) = 07/07/2017
Current Escrow Balance : $-20000.25
Escrow Disbursements During Trial : $5691.06
Anticipated Balance(Projected Escrow Advance) : $-28481.31                    
Monthly Tax Amount(Property Taxes) : $548.51                                                       Monthly Insurance Amount (Hazard Insurance): $97.33
"Monthly PMI / MI Amount(Mortgage Insurance)    : $0"
```

Comment: what did you try and what were the results?  Update your original post. Did you want to include the dollar sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('New-Escrowed Payment Quote: Effective Date(Projected - Good Through) = 07/07/2017 Current Escrow Balance : $-20000.25 Escrow Disbursements During Trial : $5691.06 Anticipated Balance(Projected Escrow Advance) : $-28481.31
Monthly Tax Amount(Property Taxes) : $548.51 Monthly Insurance Amount (Hazard Insurance): $97.33 "Monthly PMI / MI Amount(Mortgage Insurance) : $0',
'(Monthly Tax Amount\(Property Taxes\) : \$)([0-9\.]+)',1,1,'i',2) s FROM dual
```

That uses a regular expression with 2 groups:

- (Monthly Tax Amount(Property Taxes) : \$) -- The first one represents the amount title
- ([0-9.]+) -- The second one represents the amount you want to get

The last parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` tells Oracle that you want to get just the second group of the regular expression.

Comment: Wonderful ! The solution worked. Thanks for the quick help and also the explanation of how it works.

Comment: Can you also help me with extracting each of the components?  in the above text. I mean extracting each of the amounts next to each item?

Comment: You just need to change the amount title in the regular expression. If it has parentheses in it, make sure you put a \ before them. For example: (Monthly Insurance Amount \(Hazard Insurance\): \$)([0-9\.]+), (Escrow Disbursements During Trial : \$)([0-9\.]+), and so on...

Comment: I was able to make minor changes and extract amounts for all the items. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use a lot of Regex but another solution would be something like the below. You may need to adapt the line endings chr(10), chr(13) depending on the line ending that you are using (unix, windows)

```
declare

v_string varchar2(32000) default 'New-Escrowed Payment Quote: Effective Date(Projected - Good Through) = 07/07/2017
        Current Escrow Balance : $-20000.25
        Escrow Disbursements During Trial : $5691.06
        Anticipated Balance(Projected Escrow Advance) : $-28481.31
        Monthly Tax Amount(Property Taxes) : $548.51
        Monthly Insurance Amount (Hazard Insurance): $97.33
        Monthly PMI / MI Amount(Mortgage Insurance) : $0';

v_output varchar2(30) default null;

begin

select substr(v_string, instr(v_string, 'Taxes)')+ 9, (instr(v_string, chr(10), instr(v_string, 'Taxes)'))) - instr(v_string, 'Taxes)')) into v_output from dual;

dbms_output.put_line(v_output);

end;
```